# Condition for a matrix to belong to this set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $M_{2n}(k)$ be the set of all $2n \times 2n$ matrices over $k$. Define the $n \times n$ matrix $A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
  0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots  \\
  1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$ and the $2n \times 2n$ matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}
  O & A  \\
  -A & O \end{pmatrix}
$.

Let $Sp=\{x \in M_{2n}(k): x^tB+Bx=O \}$. Under which condition is a matrix $x \in M_{2n}(k)$ in $Sp$? By condition I mean something like: $x$ is skew-symmetric, or Hermitian, or it has determinant 1, or something along these lines.

I can't find an "obvious" condition, because I can't keep track of all the different indices while performing the calculations!

Thanks!

P.S. I noticed that $B$ is skew-symmetric, so $x^tB+Bx=O \iff(B^tx)^t+Bx=Bx-(Bx)^t=O$, i.e. $Bx=(Bx)^t$. Even with this in mind, I keep getting confused over the indices and I can't find a condition for $x$.

Comment: Don't look at the indices. What does $B$ do to the rows/columns of the matrix when it's multiplied on the left/right, respectively?

Comment: And you might want to look at $x$ as a block matrix of $4$ $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: @Casteels I manage to get an answer: that is $x$ has to be skew-symmetric with trace $0$. Does it make sense?

Comment: I didn't work out details, but it seems like a possible answer.

Comment: @Casteels Thank you! I hope it is correct! It seems sensible but I don't trust my calculations.

Comment: By the way, skew-symmetric already implies trace $0$ (in fact, all $0$'s on the diagonal), so you don't need that condition, if that's indeed the answer.

Comment: On second thought, I think the answer is more complicated unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that for an $n\times n$ matrix $X$, $AX$ reverses the rows of $X$, while $XA$ reverses the columns of $X$. $A$ is known as an [exchange matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix).

So, suppose that $x$, in block form, equals $$x=\left(\begin{matrix} X & Y\\ Z & W\end{matrix}\right).$$

So for $x$ to be in $Sp$, we need $$\left(\begin{matrix} AZ & AW \\ -AX & -AY\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} Z^TA & -X^TA \\ W^TA & -Y^TA\end{matrix}\right).$$

So $AZ=Z^TA$ and $AY=Y^TA$. So $X$ and $Y$ are [persymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix) matrices.

The other condition we need is that $AW=-(AX)^T$. This translates into (I think) the $i$th row of $W$ equals the negative of the reverse of $(n-i)$th column of $X$. I'm not sure if there is nice terminology for such a pair of matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes more sense now!